# Javascript (Google Scripts) value from a function is not returning

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I think could be a simple one to solve, I am stuck working this simple issue out.

I have called a createEvent function to create a google calendar event.
As part of this function I also get the google calendar event ID as EventId and want to return it.

For some reason I dont quite understand, the EventId value will not return.

```
  var EventId;

  createEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,desc,EventId);

  Logger.log('id after func = '+EventId);

   sheet.getRange(lr,EventIdHolder,1,1).setValue(EventId);
};

function createEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,desc,EventId) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var start = new Date(startDt);
  var end = new Date(endDt);
//Manually set the Location, this can be modified to be dynamic by modifying the code if need be
  //var loc = sheet.getRange(lr,destId,1,1).getValue();
  var loc = "Some Location"
//Set the Options, in this case we are only using Description and Location, as we do not need Guests or sendInvites
  var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
      description : desc,
      location : loc
  });
   Logger.log('event = '+event);

   var EventId = event.getId();

   Logger.log('id generated = '+EventId);

   return EventId;

};
```

Comment: What do the `log`s output?

Comment: [15-06-20 03:53:40:336 AEST] id generated = u32ce2tt81uvlgu0t7nf2ii1ho@google.com
[15-06-20 03:53:40:336 AEST] id after func = undefined

Comment: Something's not right about the start of the code snippet you've posted - please double check your actual code and update the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I'm not A JavaScript expert, I'd find it more logical to write it like that (assigning a value directly to the `EventId` variable) :

```
  ...
  var EventId = createEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,desc);
  Logger.log('id after func = '+EventId);
  sheet.getRange(lr,EventIdHolder,1,1).setValue(EventId);
}

function createEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,desc) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var start = new Date(startDt);
  var end = new Date(endDt);
  //Manually set the Location, this can be modified to be dynamic by modifying the code if need be
  //var loc = sheet.getRange(lr,destId,1,1).getValue();
  var loc = "Some Location"
  //Set the Options, in this case we are only using Description and Location, as we do not need Guests or sendInvites
  var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
    description : desc,
    location : loc
  });
  Logger.log('event = '+event);
  var EventId = event.getId();
  Logger.log('id generated = '+EventId);
  return EventId; 
}
```

note : I agree with Mogsdad comment below about semicolumns not being mandatory... Anyway, the code was working without it ;-)

Comment: You beat me to it, Serge. There is no pass-by-reference for strings in Javascript. Refer to [Does JavaScript pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference).

Comment: Hey ! sorry ;-D, but feel free to give a better explanation, I'll certainly read it with great interest !

Comment: All that was missing in yours was the "why" - that link explains it. Now your answer is perfect!

Comment: Just read the post you refer to, it is indeed very clear (a 137 score is not bad at all!), now I know "why" too ! thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I am very new to js and this helps me to understand .Awesome...yes code all works now.